# Is there a way to know source of navigator.geolocation coords?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Is it possible to determine wether navigator.geolocation coords are from a GPS or generated some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

However, you could check the [`.coords.accuracy`](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#accuracy) attribute to find out if it's likely to be GPS or something else (like nearby WLANs).

<strike>Edit: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_geolocation at least Firefox does not provide this attribute. So in this case you are out of luck.</strike>

Edit 2: According to the firebug console the attribute *is* actually available. On my work PC which does not have wireless, it's `25000` for example.

> accuracy | double | The accuracy of position information, in meters. Read only.

So the value makes sense, when testing on Google maps the position in my case was not very accurate.

**Conclusion:**

If finding out if the location is accurate or not is sufficient for you, go with *accuracy*. Otherwise you are out of luck.

Comment: Thanks for this, how does accuracy work? Is lower better? And how is calculated?

Comment: That's up to the implementation. Since it's a value in meters, lower is better.